# What's wrong with this Perl code to push a hash onto an array?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I'm trying to make an array of hashes.  This is my code.  The $1, $2, etc are matched from a regular expression and I've checked they exist.

**Update:** Fixed my initial issue, but now I'm having the problem that my array is not growing beyond a size of 1 when I push items onto it...

**Update 2:** It is a scope issue, as the @ACLs needs to be declared outside the loop.  Thanks everyone!

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    my @ACLs = ();

    #Accept ACLs
    if($_ =~ /access-list\s+\d+\s+(deny|permit)\s+(ip|udp|tcp|icmp)\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(\s+eq (\d+))?/i){

        my %rule = (
            action => $1, 
            protocol => $2, 
            srcip => $3, 
            srcmask => $4, 
            destip => $5, 
            destmask => $6, 
        );
        if($8){
            $rule{"port"} = $8;
        }
        push @ACLs, \%rule;
        print "Got an ACL rule.  Current number of rules:" . @ACLs . "\n";
```

The array of hashes doesn't seem to be getting any bigger.

Comment: @OP: Still having the problem with the edited code? If not, please revert.

Comment: Yes I'm still having problem with updated code

Comment: You need to declare `@ACLs` outside of your `while` loop. Using `my` inside the loop declares a new array each time through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are pushing `$rule`, which does not exist. You meant to push a reference to `%rule`:

```
push @ACLs, \%rule;
```

Always start your programs with `use strict; use warnings;`. That would have stopped you from trying to push `$rule`.

**Update:** In Perl, an array can only contain scalars. The way complex data structures are constructed is by having an array of hash references. Example:

```
my %hash0 = ( key0 => 1, key1 => 2 );
my %hash1 = ( key0 => 3, key1 => 4 );
my @array_of_hashes = ( \%hash0, \%hash1 );
# or: = ( { key0 => 1, key1 => 2 }, { key0 => 3, key1 => 4 ] );

print $array_of_hashes[0]{key1}; # prints 2
print $array_of_hashes[1]{key0}; # prints 3
```

Please read the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Comment: How can I push the data itself onto the array?  I am updating the %rule each time, so I need to push the data rather than the reference.

Comment: @Stewart: Could you specify what kind of structure you expect in the end? `%rule` is a hash while `@ACLs` is an array, so by just pushing the values of `%rule`, you would lose the information in the keys.

Comment: In the end I want @ACLs to be an array of hashes.  The hashes are lists of key/value pairs.  So the resulting data structure looks like a table

Comment: @Stewart: That's how you represent an array of hashes in Perl. I've updated my answer with more information. (I suppose that `@ACLs` is in a higher scope in your original code.)

Comment: And every time this code is executed in a loop, the `my %rule` should get a new memory allocation, right? For some reason, my array is not getting any bigger, even though I keep pushing hashes onto it.

Comment: @Stewart: Exactly. Did you change `push %rule` to `push \%rule`? If so, please supply more code.

Comment: Turns out I made a mistake with where I declared the my @ACLs.

Comment: @Stewart: That's what I meant with a "higher scope" :)

Answer (score 2):

```
my %rule = [...]

push @ACLs, $rule;
```

These two lines refer to two separate variables: a hash and a scalar. They are not the same.

It depends on what you're waning to do, but there are two solutions:

```
push @ACLs, \%rule;
```

would push a reference into the array.

```
push @ACLs, %rule;
```

would push the individual values (as in `$key1`, `$value1`, `$key2`, `$value2`...) into the array.

Answer (score 2):

You’re clearing `@ACLs` each time through the loop.  Your `my` is misplaced.